# How can I prevent bluetooth keyboard disconnect after inactivity whenever my computer is on?

Tags: windows-10, keyboard, bluetooth

I have two [Microsoft Surface Ergonomic bluetooth keyboards](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/p/surface-ergonomic-keyboard/90pnc9ljwpx9), one at work and one at home.

With my work laptop running Windows 10 Pro, the keyboard is always 'on' and functional, ever since I did the [traditional fix for this issue](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/2758967/a-bluetooth-mouse-or-keyboard-fails-to-reconnect-after-being-left-idle) (turning off the setting in Device Manager that allows the computer to turn off the bluetooth radio to save power). This works great, and I've never had a problem with it.

I recently built a new PC at home (also running Windows 10 Pro), and I'm encountering an issue where after some period of inactivity (usually at some point after 5 minutes), the keyboard is not 'on', and only after 30 seconds+, sometimes longer) of hitting keys will it turn back on/reconnect However, my bluetooth mouse still works when this happens, indicating that the bluetooth radio is still on. I have tried the same [traditional fix](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/2758967/a-bluetooth-mouse-or-keyboard-fails-to-reconnect-after-being-left-idle) that I did on my work computer, but it does not help. This same keyboard did not have the issue on my previous home-build PC, running Windows 10, so I know it's not a hardware issue with that particular keyboard.

Are there other options to try to get the keyboard to stay on, or at least resume quicker, after a period of inactivity?

Comment: Hey, I'm facing the same issue. Have you found a solution?

Comment: @david114 I haven't found a solution, but I have discovered a way to alleviate the issue somewhat. As I mentioned in my question, when the keyboard is not responding, my bluetooth mouse still functions. If I move the mouse and press a key on the keyboard it wakes up much faster than without moving the mouse. Usually within one or two key presses. Not perfect, but better.